# exception-handling method exit without finishing

Tags: java, exception

I am learning about exception handling and now I have a question.
I think the result of this code is 345,however,I don't know why the result is 35.
Shouldn't it run the code System.out.println(4)  even though there is an exception happened?

```
public class Six {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            method1();
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            System.out.println(5);
        } 
    }

    static void method1() { 
        try {
            method2();
            System.out.println(1);
        } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println(2); 
        } finally {
            System.out.println(3); 
        }
        System.out.println(4); 
    }

    static void method2() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException exception is not handle by catch block , that is why  System.out.println(4); statement is not executed

Comment: I got a stupid mistake,now I understand! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `method2()` a `NullPointerException` is thrown whereas in `method1()` you only catch `ArithmethicException` which is a different Exception. In this case the the catch block of `method1()` is not processed. Only the finally block will be executed and then the method exits and the exception is re-thrown to the calling method (`main()`)

Answer (score 0):

No, 4 is not printed because the NullPointerException is still active, it was not caught at that point. The finally block (where 3 is printed) is guaranteed to be executed so you can do cleanup there, but it does not 'stop' the exception.